# How to add unexported functions to R Package

Tags: r, function, r-package

I am working on a `R Package` with several functions that I use in one exported function.

My question, probably a silly one, is where am I supposed to put all these **unexported** functions? Or how can I make this possible?

I don't want to let user access this functions from `R/` directory.

Here is my fictitious function that uses the unexported function `add`:

```
my_func <- function(x, y){
   result <- exp(add(x, y))
   return(result)
   }
```

And here is my fictitious function `add` that I do not want to export:

```
add <- function(x, y) {
 result <- x + y
 return(result)
}
```

Thank you

## EDIT

If I put all functions in `/R` they will be "visible" for user. For example, `generate.cv.folds` from `xgboost` package is unexported but you still can access it with `xgboost:::generate.cv.folds`and I want to do the same.

Comment: You must explicitly export all function (in `/R`) you want user to have direct access to (through the `::` mechanism). All non-explicitly exported functions are not exported and accessible only through `:::`. You cannot hide code (sorry?).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik but where (or how) can I put those non-explicitly exported functions in? I know that any user can access any functions with `package:::function` but I don't want them to be visible in the `/R`. Thank you.

Comment: Your R code should be in `/R`, AFAIK. At least if you want a fully fledged package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R does not provide infrastructure for hiding source code[1]. Doing that is against the R developers' values and wishes.

So, what you want to do is not possible with R.

[1] http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/how-to-hide-code-of-any-function-td4474822.html

Comment: I do not want to hide anything. I just want to not export a function to my `R/`. See the Edit in the post. I just want to do something like that. Besides, I am against private source code, since I want to users use it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking then. If a function is exported is specified in the NAMESPACE file as described in the Writing R Extensions manual. It is not true that functions defined in the /R directory are exported automatically.

Comment: Thank you @Roland! Probably I am making a confusion with the terms. Did you see the Edit part when I cite an example of a "non-visible" function? The function `generate.cv.folds` from `xgboost` is not "visible" in `R/` (as you can see in the [xgboost GitHub](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/R-package/R/xgb.cv.R) ) but it is not in the Xgboost GitHUb `R/` directory.

Comment: ??? https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/R-package/R/utils.R#L178

Comment: I think you just don't understand how the NAMESPACE file works. `generate.cv.folds` is not exported there: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/R-package/NAMESPACE

Comment: I see now!! Thank you @Roland! It really helps me.

Comment: That's the problem. I was not understanding how NAMESPACE works, but now I kinda do. Thank you @Roland

Comment: "kinda" is often not enough. I encourage you to study *Writing R Extensions* .

Answer (score 2):

Exporting/not exporting a function is as easy as adding a single line to the function's documentation.  I'll assume you're using roxygen2 to document your package.

Exported:

```
#' Add two numeric values
#'
#' This function returns the sum of two values.
#' @param x,y Numeric values.
#' @return Numeric.
#' @export
add1 <- function(x, y) {
 result <- x + y
 return(result)
}
```

Not exported:

```
#' Add two numeric values.
#'
#' This function returns the sum of two values.
#' @param x,y Numeric values.
#' @return Numeric.
add2 <- function(x, y) {
 result <- x + y
 return(result)
}
```

Note the missing `@export` at the end of the documentation. When you create the documentation, the NAMESPACE file will look like:

`export(add1)`

but it will not have an entry for `add2`.